# Writing data to Firestore on create user not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using the VueCLI & Firebase (Auth & Firestore).

Essentially the function is being called properly and registers the user in the database correctly, however, the promises aren't being called (e.g. .then & .catch) on the .createUserWithEmailAndPassword function.

No error is returned and nothing is registered in the firestore, has really stumped me.

However, sometimes it works exactly as expected?? But often irregularly.

```
submit () {
  var v = this

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(v.form.email, v.form.password)
    .then(function () {
      // set account  doc
      var account = {
        email: v.form.email,
        name: v.form.name,
        picture: v.form.picture
      }
      db.collection('Users').doc(v.form.email).set(account).then(() => {
        console.log('Database Details Defined')
        // Set user display name
        v.$store.commit('setUserDisplayName', v.form.name)
        // Set user display name
        v.$store.commit('setUserImage', v.form.picture)
        // Set user as signed in
        v.$store.commit('changeLoginState', true)
        // Set user email
        v.$store.commit('setUserEmail', v.form.email)

        // console.log('Vue Store Details Defined')

        localStorage.setItem('name', v.$store.state.displayName)
        localStorage.setItem('email', v.$store.state.email)
        localStorage.setItem('userImage', v.$store.state.userImage)
        localStorage.setItem('loggedin', v.$store.state.isLoggedin)

        // console.log('Local Storage Details Defined')

        // Redirect user to dashboard
        v.$router.replace('/')
        v.registering = false
      }).catch((error) => {
        v.databaseError = 'Database Error: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message
        v.registering = false
      })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      v.registrationError = 'Registration Error: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message
      v.registering = false
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add `console.log("Creating user")` in `submit()` function and check if that function is actually running? Also is the page refreshing on submit because that's intended behavior of forms?

Comment: Weird! Added it and it still registered the user in Firebase but didn't call the console log which came before - the HTML is not a `<form>` it's just a `<div>`

Comment: Try restarting the server. Maybe it still ran the old code?

Comment: Okay doing that managed to get the log called - same outcome otherwise

Comment: If you `console.log(account)` similarly right before the `set()` statement, does it log all the values as expected? Also can you please keep the network tab in browser open and check if any request is being made to Firestore ?

Comment: Alright everything seemed to work when I used a completely unique email - but I the tried again using an email I know I've used before (the user had since been deleted)

We got up to `console.log("Creating User)` but the account was not logged, and there were some entries in the network tab for firebase.js that the status was 'cancelled'

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of response tab of that cancelled request? There must be some clue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236035/discussion-between-benelwoods-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a function `getDB()` that returns the value the Firestore instance so `getDB().collection("users")...` may have worked as intended. I don't see where `db` is initialized in this specific file so `console.log(db)` might help to check what is it's value.

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc(v.form.email).set(account)
```

This worked as intended because `firebase.firestore()` will return the Firestore instance for sure. I'd recommend exporting Firebase services directly and not in functions. For example you could create a file `firebase.js` and initialize Firebase there:

```js
var firebase = require('firebase/app')
require('firebase/firestore')

const firebaseConfig = { }

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const auth = firebase.auth()
const db = firebase.firestore()

export {db, auth}
```

You need to initialize Firebase only once as shown. It'll be much more clear rather than initializing in the `getDB` function.